# Can anybody help me to know the type of land covers in DIVA GIS data?

Tags: raster, classification, land-cover, diva-gis

I have dowloaded the country mask land cover data from DIVA GIS website. I don't see the name of different types of land covers.

Comment: Please add the link to the data and/or show a sample of the data here. What software do you use to view the data and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I have downloaded the data from DIVA website, here is the link: diva-gis.org/gdata .... I have opened in qGIS and also DIVA, I got the thematic map raster with the colors and values but no names ... Thanks

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen in the sources section of de data download page; DIVA is just a portal for different data sources. The land cover data's original source is GLC2000 (as can be seen in the table): which after simply searching on Google leads to this [page](http://forobs.jrc.ec.europa.eu/products/glc2000/legend.php) for your answer.